# apply lambda: delete the corresponding characters of A according to the multiple keywords of B

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, replace, substitution

How to delete the corresponding character in another column based on the value of a column?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['ABCD','B'],['ABFJS','A,J'],['DGQEX','']],
                   index = [1,2,3],columns=['A','B'])
```

Example: I want to delete "ABCD" in the first row according to "B" and keep "ACD". Similarly, I want to delete "A" and "J" in the second row of 'ABFJS' according to 'A,J' and keep "BFS". The third line is unchanged.
How can I do this?
I have tried this, but it doesn't work

```
df.apply(    lambda x: [   x["A"].replace(i, "")  for i in str(x["B"]).split(",") ], axis=1)
```

returned in the second line is [BFJS, ABFS] instead of [BFS]

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex' [`re.sub()`](https://www.codecademy.com/resources/docs/python/regex/sub) function like so:

```
df.apply(lambda x: re.sub("|".join(x['B'].split(',')), "", x["A"]), axis=1)
```

Print out:

```
1      ACD
2      BFS
3    DGQEX
```